# Как отсортировать список с помощью компаратора?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Как отсортировать список `python3` с помощью компаратора, который сравнивает два элемента?
Я знаю, что в `python` в функции `sort` есть ключевой аргумент `key`, но он получает лишь один элемент, а мне нужно сравнить два. Я пробовал использовать функцию `cmp_to_key`, но она не работает.

код, который я пытался заставить работать:

```py
import functools


a = []


def f(g, h):
    p = 1.0
    k = 1.0
    i = 9
 
    while i + 1:
        k = a[h][i]**k / a[g][i]
        if p > 99 and abs(k - 1) > 0.02:
            break
        k = 1 if abs(k - 1) < 1e-10 else k**p
        
        if not 0.11 < k < 9:
            break
        
        p = a[g][i]**p
        i -= 1
 
    print(g, h, k > 1)
    return k > 1


g = []
h = []
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    g.append(i);
    h.append(0);
    *l, = map(int, input().split())
    k = l[0]
    k += 1
    u = True;

    a.append([])
    for o in l[1:]:
        u = 0 if o < 2 else u
        a[i].append(o if u else 1)

    for _ in " " * (10 - k):
        a[i].append(1)

# s(0, n - 1)
print(*map(lambda x: x + 1, sorted(g, key=functools.cmp_to_key(f))))
```

Ввод:

```
10
4 2 2 2 2 2
1 2 2
1 3 2
1 2 3
3 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
1 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
2 4 3 3
2 2 3 4
```

Начальный массив для сортировки:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Каким должен быть вывод:

```
2 4 3 6 7 5 9 10 1 8
```

Какой вывод я получаю:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: cmp_to_key работает. Добавьте код, как вы пытались сделать.

Comment: @insolor вы сможете помочь?

Comment: [python, sort list with two arguments in compare function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46851676/2881286)

Comment: ожидаемый вывод приведен. Какой вывод ты сейчас получаешь? Почему ты думаешь, что именно он неверен?

Comment: @Grundy я получаю изначальный массив `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо вам за вашу помощь! Ссылка, которую вы дали, мне помогла, программа действительно стала работать как надо! спасибо, вы можете добавить эту ссылку как ответ, и я отмечу его как правильный)

Comment: @zolars, какой именно вариант помог? Если посмотреть `cmp_to_key` - то в нем как раз и создается класс с методом `__lt__`

Comment: @Grundy Ну, я создал класс `Tower` и добавил туда метод `__lt__`  :/

Comment: @zolars, [cmp_to_key](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py#L206) по сути делает то же самое с переданной функцией

Comment: @Grundy Но у меня, почему-то, когда я использую `cmp_to_key` массив остается таким же

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141993/discussion-between-grundy-and-zolars).

Comment: @zolars Разве вы не получили ответ на последний заданный вопрос про число в степени? Почему вы считаете возможным стирать и чужой труд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компаратор переданный в `cmp_to_key` должен возвращать численное значение.

В вопросе функция возвращает `boolean`.

Так как `k` сравнивается с единицей равносильным переходом к числу будет

```
k-1
1-k
```

В зависимости от направления сортировки.

Answer (score 4):

Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией `cmp_to_key` из модуля `functools`:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def comparator(x, y):
    return x - y

a = [7, 3, 6, 10, 5, 2, 1]

print(sorted(a, key=cmp_to_key(comparator)))
```

Вывод:

> `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10]`

Comment: Прочитайте пожалуйста мой вопрос внимательнее, я написал, что я пробовал, но эта фунеция не работает

Comment: @zolars так может вы функцию неправильно применяете? я вам предоставил блок кода, который сортирует список при помощи `cmp_to_key`, как тогда понимать "не работает"?

Comment: значит, что не сортирует. я сортирую массивы массивов, со сложной функцией возведения в степень, и в этом случае, оно не работает